# Системные логи в logback

Tags: java, логирование, logback

При использовании логгера logback, часть логов - системные - пишутся в стандартном формате, правила из appender не применяются. Подскажите, что следует добавить, чтобы работало для всех логов?
На изображении вверху стандартные логи, ниже - модифицированные, такие как должны быть везже

[image]